Прошу совета, вывод данных из datagrid в listview
У меня есть форма на которой есть datagrid, в ней уже есть строки из базы SSMS они выводятся и всё отлично. Я хотел сделать так: чтобы при выборе определённой строки в datagrid и нажатия на кнопку осуществлялся переход на другую форму, в которой есть listview с textblock'ами они привязаны к этой же таблице что и в datagrid, но выводились данные именно из той строки которую я выбрал перед нажатием на кнопку на форме с datagrid.
Искал ответы, не нашел ничего дельного, сам понимаю как перейти, как наполнить datagrid и listview данными, но не понимаю как выполнить именно такую задумку, описанную выше.
Если нужен фрагмент моего кода, то я с удовольствием поделюсь, лишь бы кто помог...
P.S. Я прошу вас, если вы ответите на этот вопрос, прислав мне ссылку на справочник по языку C# или справочник по WPF, мне это не надо! я не собираюсь штудировать всю инфу ради одной задачи.

Нашел решение, довольно быстро, более конкретно задал вопрос в браузере и нашел форум с отличным ответом:
var current = Entities.GetContext().Table.ToList();
ListView.ItemsSource = current.OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToList();

Почему то изначально до этого не додумался

Зачем 2 раза ToList? Уберите его в первой строчке, быстрее отработает.

А SelectedItem уже не модно использовать, что ли?
